# Java Float vs. Long performance

Tags: java, matlab, performance

I am currently in a development process of an android app that will require some digital signal processing. We wrote our code in Matlab and now we are in a process of translating the code to java. We designed a Butterworth integer filter to gain performance, but in order for it to run we must use very large integers (1e20-1e30) in the process. Is it not better (performance wise) to use primitive floats and regular Butterworth filter instead of the integer filter?

Comment: integer or long are not that long. ony bigint/bigdecimal will work for you.

Comment: Memory bandwidth is often a big deal for performance.  `float` has excellent range in only 32 bits, and good hardware support on typical ARM CPUs in Android devices.  `float` should be *much* better than extended-precision (larger than 64-bit) integer, especially if you can use NEON to process 4 `float`s in parallel.